# Why does return statement not behave as expected in the shell function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

```
function foo()
{
    ls / | while read LINE;
    do
        echo "step1"
        return
    done

    echo "step2"
}

foo
```

I expect the shell script to output:

> `step1`

However, the real output is:

> `step1`
>
> `step2`

**Why does return statement not behave as expected in the shell function?**

Comment: For the same reason that `( echo x; exit; ) ; echo y` will output x and y. The `|`creates a subshell for right like left operands. `return` applies to that subshell, not your function. Check it with `y() { ( echo x; return; ) ; echo y; }; y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the subshell induced by the pipe. `return` can be used not only to return from a function, but from a sourced file. The subshell seems to be treated similarly; `return` is no longer a function return statement, but a shell exit statement. <strike>Control "starts" to leave the function by leaving the loop, but when the subshell exits, the function "forgets" to exit. Or maybe the function doesn't actually see the `return` statement executing *because* it executes in a subshell.</strike>

(Thanks to a comment by @zilog that made me think of the sourced-file angle.)

You can enable the `lastpipe` option to get the behavior you expect, because the `|` doesn't induce a new subshell.

Comment: Hi, i guess OP question implies looking for a way to exit the function from the while subshell. I suggest you to add a way for that, like using `while` exit status through `&&`and `|| `. (`lastpipe` is fine, but could troubles following scripts/commands).